# Jekyll -- possible to cycle through all post types?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is it possible to cycle through all content types on Jekyll?

Instead of `{% for post in site.pages %}`

I want to do something like

`{% for post in site.pages or site.posts %}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/concat/) filter :

```
{% assign all = site.posts | concat: site.pages %}
{% for post in all %}
...
```

Comment: Thanks David!

Can I also do:

`{% assign all = site.posts | concat: site.pages | concat: site.exchanges %}`

exchanges is a _custom folder.

or do I need to assign that first?

Comment: Just give it a try. You can concatenate any array. The challenge may occur during the loop when you need to filter items.